# What is a potential in De-Broglie-Bohm theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-interpretations, potential

As I have so far understood, the [De-Broglie-Bohm theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) is based on two equations:

1. The Schrödinger equation.
2. The Guiding equation of the De-Broglie-Bohm theory.

In the Schrödinger equation (as always) there is a potential term. But what is a potential in the terms of the theory? Is it an electrostatic potential or a gravitational potential? Does the De-Broglie-Bohm theory need another theory to stand on or does it stand on its own?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: More on de Broglie-Bohm theory: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7112/2451 and links therein.